# Placement of Clause

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, clauses

I want to add this clause in the middle of sentence: ‘as far as I'm concerned.’

Is it wrong to place it between the auxiliary verb and the main verb, or is it only a matter of style? Which of the following is better?

> *He's a nonpareil musician who has—as far as I'm concerned—revived orchestral music with his live performances.*

or

> *He's a nonpareil musician who—as far as I'm concerned—has revived orchestral music with his live performances.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+has+in+my+opinion%2Cwho+in+my+opinion+has&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20has%20in%20my%20opinion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20in%20my%20opinion%20has%3B%2Cc0) (using the modal parenthetical 'in my opinion') show that both positions are used. Though the unseparated 'has PP' seems preferred, I'd actually prefer the separated variant in your example, as it seems to better maintain the formal register and overall flow.

Comment: Your examples show no useful difference. 

*a nonpareil musician* who has—as far as I'm concerned (anything)— or who—as far as I'm concerned—has (anything) are equivalent

That I broadly understand and had never met *nonpareil* means what, please? I suspect *nonpareil* means roughly *without equal* and so what?